# Draft mailings appear as scheduled?

Tags: 4.6.2

4.6.2: Wordpress 4.1

If I save a new mailing as draft by clicking the Save Draft button, the mailing appears in both the scheduled and unscheduled lists. Seems to me it should not appear anywhere in the scheduled list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you upgrade to 4.6.3 and try again. Quite a few bugs were fixed including one that sounds similar to the above

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16251